# how to do an enumeration in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have some chars, for example ["ab"], and I just have two number, zero and one.
And I want to get an answer like

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 1)],
 [('a', 0), ('b', 1)],
 [('a', 1), ('b', 0)],
 [('a', 0), ('b', 0)]]
```

I am a beginner, could someone help me?

Thankyou very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cartesian product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119730/cartesian-product)

Comment: Well, I don't thing so, he's looking for a special order and pairing, as it seems.

Comment: @phg This is not actual homework, and as a beginner, it is difficult for me.

Comment: @Laurent no problem. That was a reply to Daniel, since you're actually not searching for a cartesian product, like he thought first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most interesting part is generating the list of all possible sequences of `0` and `1`; one way is via `replicateM`:

```
> replicateM 2 [1,0]
[[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]
```

You can use `map` and `zip` from there:

```
> map (zip "ab") (replicateM 2 [1,0])
[[('a',1),('b',1)],[('a',1),('b',0)],[('a',0),('b',1)],[('a',0),('b',0)]]
```

To match your answer exactly, you'd have to do a tiny bit of extra munging:

```
> map (zip "ab" . reverse) (replicateM 2 [1,0])
[[('a',1),('b',1)],[('a',0),('b',1)],[('a',1),('b',0)],[('a',0),('b',0)]]
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I still can't understand, what if it is "abcd"? Does it still work?

Comment: @Laurent You may use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find functions by name or type. If you want to match up with different strings, you will need some minor changes: the `2` argument to `replicateM` should be the length of the string.

Comment: Thankyou all of you! I will remember this website, it works well, thankyou for your help.