# Providing additional arguments to map on HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I would like to do something like this:

```
def run(subjects: List[Subject]) = {
  val configs = compute()
  subjects.map(s => configs.map(c => test(s,c)))
  // or flatMap, I don't really care at this point
}
```

In my use case, subjects are actually `Subject[T]` and I need a typesafe version of `T` in the result. So I have:

```
def run[L <: HList](subjects: L)(implicit mapper: Mapper[testFun.type, L]) = {
  val configs = compute()
  subjects.map(testFun)
}
```

However, now I am unable to pass in the configurations to `testFun` which, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442440/unable-to-map-on-hlist), needs to have a singleton type.

An option would be to do:

```
val cfgHL = HList.fill(subjects.length)(configs)
(subjects zip cfgHL).map(testFun)
```

But `HList` currently does not have a `fill` operation. Any hints?

Comment: HList now has a fill method (not in the official release yet though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapConst` to accomplish the same thing as `fill`. If we have the following:

```
val xs = 1 :: 'a :: 'a' :: HNil
```

We can write:

```
scala> xs.zip(xs mapConst "x") == (1, "x") :: ('a, "x") :: ('a', "x") :: HNil
res0: Boolean = true
```

Note that there are other ways to tackle the problem of partially applying (higher-rank) polymorphic functions and then mapping with them—see for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456938/334519). Something like that is likely to be overkill for your use case, though.