# Define scalaz monad instance for a shapeless hlist

Tags: scala, types, monads, scalaz, shapeless

I've tried to define a `Monad` (scalaz) for shapeless `HList` through `point` and `bind` implementation. The first problem is that `HList` trait is not a type constructor, but that can be solved with type lambdas, `point` is simple, but i couldn't find right implementation for `bind`, i guess i need some function of type `Poly1` with some `Aux/Mapper` tricks, but that side of shapeless is still dark to me. `HList` has all functions to be a Monad, like simple List, so is it possible to implement one from Scalaz?

Comment: This isn't possible in the straightforward sense, but it's an interesting question. See for example [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14456938/334519) (involving applicative functors instead of monads), [this related example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/cartesianproduct.scala) in Shapeless, and my (unanswered) question [here](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/294064540235210752).

Comment: ScalaZ is still uncharted territory for me, but this might contain the methods and interoperability you need: [Shapeless Contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib)

Comment: mandubian (http://stackoverflow.com/users/601296/mandubian) wrote a blog post about a monoid for HList: http://mandubian.com/2014/07/29/hmonoid/ , that can be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

A monoid is a set with some operations that obey particular laws. What elements are you considering as possible `HListM[A]`? If you declare `HListM[A] = HList`, i.e. any `HList`, then you'll quickly find that you can't `map` with `f: A => B`, except by treating all `map`s as `identity` and you've reinvented the rather uninteresting monad `Id` (with a few extra but inert inhabitants).

We could make a monad with the type `HListM[A] = A :: ... :: A :: HNil` (though even actually expressing that type in Scala is a challenge - you'd need an auxiliary trait `trait CopiesOf[N <: Nat, A] {type Out <: HList`},  `implicit`s to provide instances of this, and then an existential to actually write it (`CopiesOf[N, A]#Out forSome {type N <: Nat}`)). Writing monad operations for this is possible, though you'd need to require shapeless auxiliary classes like `Prepend` at the point of operation, since there's no real way to express a "forall" type in Scala - you can declare instances of your type for `_0` and `Succ[N]`, but there's no way to prove to the compiler that there is an instance for any `N <: Nat`, you just have to require implicit ones whenever you need to use them.

But after a lot of work you'd end up with something isomorphic to `List[A]`; why not just use `List[A]` for that case?