# Options check in a HList, Scala

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, hlist

So, there are `hlists` of options:

```
val l1 = Option(1) :: Option("str") :: Option(true) :: HNil
val l2 = Option(1) :: {None: Option[String]} :: Option(false) :: HNil
```

To make a new list, consisting of all matching type objects (of their TypeTags), it is possible using the `liftA2` function ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456938/1092399 )(notice: there are repetitive types and lots of `HNil` objects in a result, but it is not a question):

```
object eq extends Poly2 {
    implicit def neq[A, B](implicit e: A =:!= B) = 
        at[Option[A], Option[B]] { case (a, b) => (HNil) }
    implicit def eq[A, B](implicit t: TypeTag[A], e: A =:= B) =
        at[Option[A], Option[B]] {(a, b) => t :: HNil}
}

liftA2(eq)(l1, l2) //> there would be all three types
```

So now the objective is to skip all empty `Option` objects (if we can do this, so there is a chance to build a list of matching all empty `Option` objects); we need smth like:

```
object eqo extends Poly2 {
    implicit def neq[A, B](implicit e: A =:!= B) = 
        at[Option[A], Option[B]] { case (a, b) => (HNil) }
    implicit def eq[A, B](implicit t: TypeTag[A], e: A =:= B) = 
        at[Option[A], Option[B]] {
            case(a, None)  => HNil
            case (None, b) => HNil
            case (a, b)    => t :: HNil
        }
}

liftA2(eqo)(l1, l2) //> result with no String type (should be)
```

The function above is wrong, cause there happens type erasure (types in a result ~ `Product with Serializable with shapeless.HList`). 
So the question: is there a way to make such check or it is completely unreal?

p.s. It is a very interesting type of `case` in this situation: `Product with Serializable with shapeless.HList`

Comment: Erasure isn't the problem—the return type of `eqo.eq` really is just `HList` (you can basically ignore the `Product with Serializable` part). You want a type that depends on values, and I can't see a straightforward way to encode that here.

Comment: Thx for the answer, heh, then I'll try to make it with a type class, and try to remove empty options from the list before usage `liftA2`.