# Combining nested lists in Scala - flattened Carthesian product

Tags: scala

I have an interesting problem which is proving difficult for someone new to Scala.
I need to combine 2 lists:

```
listA : List[List[Int]]
listB : List[Int]
```

In the following way:

```
val listA = List(List(1,1), List(2,2))
val listB = List(3,4)
val listC = ???

// listC: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,1,3),List(1,1,4),List(2,2,3),List(2,2,4)
```

In Java, I would use a couple of nested loops:

```
for(List<Integer> list : listA) {
    for(Integer i: listB) {
        subList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        subList.add(i);
        listC.add(subList);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is a one liner in Scala, but so far it's eluding me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to perform a flattened Cartesian product. For-comprehensions are the easiest way to do this and may look similar to your Java solution:

```
val listC = for (list <- listA; i <- listB) yield list :+ i
```

Comment: Note that it would be much more efficient (i.e., $n$ times more efficient, with $n$ being the size of the sublists of `listA`) to prepend the value `i` than to append it at the end of the list:

`val listC = for (list <- listA; i <- listB) yield i :: list`

Comment: In my case the order is not important, so I will use the more efficient prepend operation as suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

[scand1sk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709898/scand1sk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892595/334519) is almost certainly the approach you should be using here, but as a side note, there's another way of thinking about this problem. What you're doing is in effect *lifting* the append operation into the applicative functor for lists. This means that using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) you can write the following:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val listC = (listA |@| listB)(_ :+ _)
```

We can think of `(_ :+ _)` as a function that takes a list of things, and a single thing of the same type, and returns a new list:

```
(_ :+ _): ((List[Thing], Thing) => List[Thing])
```

Scalaz provides an applicative functor instance for lists, so we can in effect create a new function that adds an extra list layer to each of the types above. The weird `(x |@| y)(_ :+ _)` syntax says: create just such a function and apply it to `x` and `y`. And the result is what you're looking for.

And as in the for-comprehension case, if you don't care about order, you can make the operation more efficient by using `::` and flipping the order of the arguments.

For more information, see my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119898/334519) about the cartesian product in Haskell, this [introduction to applicative functors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519) in Scala, or [this blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/) about making the syntax for this kind of thing a little less ugly in Scala. And of course feel free to ignore all of the above if you don't care.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @travis-brown. Your alternative solution is also valuable to me, as I want to learn all things Scala.