# In Haskell what are the inner workings of list comprehension?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm rather new to Haskell and was looking at this post here: [Cartesian product of 2 lists in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119730/cartesian-product).

In the answer there is this snippet of code:

```
cartProd xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

Which with these two lists:

```
xs = [1,2,3]
ys = [4,5,6]
```

would yield

```
[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]
```

Had I not seen this result I would have assumed it would just have returned

```
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

because it would traverse both lists at the same time.

But now it - to programming languages I know better - looks like a double for loop used to traverse a matrix:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    for(int y = 4; y < 7; y++)
        //make tuple (x,y)
```

What causes a list comprehension to behave in this manner?

Comment: First of all, the list is not proactively constructed, but using lazy evaluation...

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I understand lazy evaluation at a very basic level but don't know it's capabilities yet.

Comment: Well the list is not "fully" generated (actually not generated at all). It simply stores the "definition", when you are interested in the first element, it will calculate the first, and construct a new expression for the remaining part, etc. You can therefore even define lists with infinite length.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, but does that have any effect on why x remains constant while y increments?

Comment: @AR7 Lazy evaluation never has an effect on *which* value is produced; all evaluation orders that terminate will produce the same value. The magic sauce of lazy evaluation is that if any evaluation order terminates, lazy evaluation does, too. In short: no, lazy evaluation has no effect on why x remains constant while y increments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [introduction](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) explains the *syntax* of list comprehension. Basically one can say that every `x <- list` means an additional nested "for"-loop to generate tuples and every predicate is simply tested. Thus the expression:

```
[(x,y) | x <- xs, even x, y <- ys, even 3*y-div x 2]
```

Would be translated in an imperative language as:

```
for (var x : xs) {
    if(even(x)) {
    for(var y : ys) {
        if(even(3*y-x/2)) {
            yield (x,y)
        }
    }
}
```

`yield` is a keyword that is sometimes used with co-routines. Furthermore as for `yield` the evaluation is done lazily. This enables for instance to generate **all** even integers as:

```
[x|x <-[2..],even x]
```

## List monads

In order to understand list comprehension fundamentally, one needs to know what [*Monads*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads) are. Every list comprehension can be translated into a *list monad*. For instance your example is translated into:

```
do x <- xs
   (do y <- ys
       return (x,y))
```

Which is again syntactical sugar for:

```
xs >>= (\x -> (ys >>= \y -> return (x,y)))
```

A monad is an important concept in functional programming (and probably one better reads the wikipedia page), because it is a bit hard to master. The sometimes say a *monads are like burritos,...*.

Once you more or less understand a monad: a monad is a type-class with a `return` statement and a `>>=` channeling statement. Now the `return` statement for the inner part is easy:

```
return x = [x]
```

So that means that each time `x` and `y` are set, you will create a tuple `(x,y)` and return it as a singleton list: thus `[(x,y)]`. Now the "bind" operator `>>=` needs to "glue" `ys` and `\y -> return (x,y)` together. This is done by implementing it as:

```
(>>=) xs f = concat $ map f xs
```

In other words you do a mapping and concatenate the result of the mapping.

Now if take the second part of the unsugared expression into account:

```
ys >>= \y -> return (x,y)
```

It means that for a given `x` (we now abstract away), we will map every element in `ys` to a tuple `(x,y)` and return it. We will thus generate a list of lists with every list being a singleton containing a tuple. Something like (if `ys=[1,2]`):

```
[[(x,1)],[(x,2)]]
```

Now the `>>=` will furthermore `concat` it into:

```
\x -> [(x,1),(x,2)]
```

Until now, we've abstracted the `x` away (assumed it was one). But now we can take the first part of that expression:

```
xs >>= \x -> [(x,1),(x,2)]
```

If `xs=[3,5]`, it means we will create again lists:

```
[[(3,1),(3,2)],[(5,1),(5,2)]]
```

and after the concat:

```
[(3,1),(3,2),(5,1),(5,2)]
```

Which is what we expect for:

```
[(x,y)|x<-[3,5],y<-[1,2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've been reading through "Learn You A Haskell" and I haven't gotten to Monads yet which is probably why I'm confused.

Comment: Well the monad part is a bit hard, but it is important for deep understanding of some functional programming concepts. After reading monads, one starts to understand most of Haskell is syntactical sugar for monadic concepts.

Comment: @AR7 It is not necessary to understand monads in their full generality to understand list comprehensions. The other answer gives the Haskell Report's actual desugaring translation for list comprehensions (which is more complete than the one suggested in this answer), and mentions monads exactly zero times.

Comment: It *could* be translated like that, but it is not. In fact, in the latest GHC version, it ends up going in precisely the opposite direction! List comprehensions actually desugar in one of two different ways, one of them full of invocations to `foldr` and `build`, and one full of recursive functions.

Comment: The Haskell Report, on the other hand, explains list comprehensions in terms of `concatMap`.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the Haskell Report, list comprehensions are evaluated as follows:

```
[ e | True ]   = [e]
[ e | q ]      = [ e | q, True ]
[ e | b,  Q  ] = if b then [ e | Q ] else []
[ e | p <- l,  Q ] = let ok p = [ e | Q ]
                         ok _ = []
                     in concatMap ok  l
[ e | let decls,  Q ] = let decls in [ e | Q ]
```

In your case, the relevant part is, since the pattern `p` is just a variable `x`:

```
[ e | x <- l, Q ] = concatMap (\x -> [ e | Q ]) l
```

More concretely, the comprehension `[(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]` is translated to

```
concatMap (\x -> [(x,y) | y <- ys]) xs
```

Which is, by definition of `concatMap`

```
concat (map (\x -> [(x,y) | y <- ys]) xs)
```

Let's substitute concrete values for `xs`,`ys`:

```
concat (map (\x -> [(x,y) | y <- [4,5,6]]) [1,2,3])
```

Applying `map`:

```
concat [ [(1,y) | y <- [4,5,6]] 
       , [(2,y) | y <- [4,5,6]] 
       , [(3,y) | y <- [4,5,6]] ]
```

Evaluating the inner list comprehensions: (these could be translated again using the laws above, but I'll make it short)

```
concat [ [(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)]
       , [(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)]
       , [(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)] ]
```

And by concatenating the above lists we obtain the result,

```
       [  (1,4),(1,5),(1,6) 
       ,  (2,4),(2,5),(2,6) 
       ,  (3,4),(3,5),(3,6)  ]
```

---

Note that GHC also implements as a Haskell extension the so-called *parallel list comprehensions*, which do operate as you expected:

```
> :set -XParallelListComp
> [(x,y)| x<-[1,2,3] | y <-[4,5,6]]
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

Internally, they use the `zip` (or rather, `zipWith`) function.

Answer (score 1):

The ideas behind list comprehension syntax comes from [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) in mathematics.

In mathematics, one can write something like:

```
{ (x, y) | x ∈ xs, y ∈ ys }
```

To mean "the set of all elements of the form (x, y), where x is an element of the set xs and y is an element of the set ys".

Now we want to take this set-builder idea and turn it into a "list-builder" syntax for programming languages. So we want this:

```
[ (x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
```

To mean "the list containing all elements of the form (x, y), where x was an element obtained from xs and y is an element obtained from ys".

Obviously if this list notation produced the list `[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]` (when `xs = [1, 2, 3]` and `ys = [4, 5, 6]`) it simply wouldn't be all the pairs of the required form: `(1, 6)` is an element that can be obtained from `xs` paired with an element that can be obtained from `ys`, but it's not in your list.

So the really trite answer to "What causes a list comprehension to behave in this manner?" is that it was **programmed** to behave in that manner, because that's how the people who came up with it wanted it to behave.

There are many different ways you can program this behaviour. You can (as the OP noticed) use nested loops, or you can use functions like `map` and `concat`, or you can use the Monad instance for lists, etc. As such, you can translate list comprehension syntax into any of these in order to demonstrate that list comprehensions are "really monadic" or "really nested loops" or whatever.

But fundamentally, list comprehensions are combinatorial rather than zipping because the language designers deliberately chose the syntax to mean that, in order for it to be a bit like set-builder notation in mathematics<sup>1</sup>. That "x remains constant while y increments" isn't just an interesting quirk of the implementation, the implementation was *chosen* specifically to do that. If there were some alternate universe where the list monad (or nested loops, etc) wasn't useful for this purpose, list comprehensions would not produce different results in that universe, they would be implemented some other way to produce the same results.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are significant differences between list comprehension syntax and set-builder notation, even though they look obviously similar. A fundamental difference comes from using lists rather than sets; an element is simply either in a set or not, but lists contain elements at specific indices (including the possibility of containing a given element at multiple indices).

So list comprehension syntax has to define the *order* it will produce its elements (and exactly how many elements it will produce), and that makes list comprehensions fundamentally about **enumeration**, whereas set-builder notation is fundamentally about **membership**. The set-builder notation `{ (x, y) | x ∈ xs, y ∈ ys }` is really saying "you can answer whether a given (x, y) is in the set we're building by checking whether x ∈ xs and y ∈ ys", while the list comprehension `[ (x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys ]` is saying "you can enumerate the elements of the list we're building by enumerating `xs` and then for every element also enumerate `ys`"

Comment: we could see the LC notation more abstractly, as a "bag" notation: lists, with duplicates allowed, but without positions associated to the elements. after all nothing in LC notation can give us the positions, without the explicit use of `zip`. the notation could work on any data type, and in fact it does so, with `MonadComprehensions`.  a language could conceivably have a "nondeterministic collection" (built-in, opaque) type which would do everything in parallel, as one example. the map `[f x | x <- xs]` would still be well defined. in fact in Scheme, `map`'s eval order is unknown/unspecified.

Comment: @WillNess All of that is true, but the order of elements is clearly part of the interface of Haskell lists, so any expression producing a list (that isn't impure) needs to result in a well-determined order. MonadComprehensions generalise the syntax to mean different things for different types, but for lists it still means combinatorial enumeration (of elements if you're thinking about lists as collections, or of possibilities if you've got your "list monad models nondeterminism" hat on).