# Use anonymous function as parameter

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function, type-signature

So i currently have this function for generating all possible combinations

```
func :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
func xs ys = concat(map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y))ys) xs)
```

Now I want to extend it so that i can filter it using an anonymous function as parameter.

Example:

```
func [1,2,3] [4,5] (\ a b -> a+b > 6) -> [(2,5),(3,4),(3,5)]
```

I tried to change the Typesignature of func:

from:
[a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]

to:
[a] -> [b] -> (a1 -> a1 -> Bool) -> t

But it did not work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just changing the signature is not enough, you'll have to accept the fucntion and apply it somewhere in the definition of your function.

Comment: The last signature is way too general: it claims that given any two lists of type `[a]` and `[b]`, and a function `a1->a1->Bool` (where `a1` is a completely arbitrary type, unrelated to the previous lists), will produce a result of an arbitrary type `t` (caller's choice!). That can't be correct. Probably you want `[a] -> [b] -> (a->b->Bool) -> [(a,b)]`. To implement this I'd use something involving `zip`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)

So now I have this:
`func :: [a] -> [b] -> ((a,b) -> Bool) -> [(a, b)]`
`func xs ys f = filter f (tup)`
    `where`
        `tup = concat(map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y))ys) xs)`

But when I run it i get an error:


• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                  with actual type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’
    • The lambda expression ‘\ a b -> a + b > 7’
      has two value arguments,
        but its type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’ has only one

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP has stated that they changed their code to

```hs
func :: [a] -> [b] -> ((a,b) -> Bool) -> [(a, b)]
func xs ys f = filter f (tup)
  where tup = concat(map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y))ys) xs)
```

followed by what one assumes is

```hs
func [1,2,3] [4,5] (\a b -> a + b > 7)
```

which gives them the error

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’
• The lambda expression ‘\ a b -> a + b > 7’ has two value arguments, but its type ‘(a, b) -> Bool’ has only one
```

This is easy to fix; in fact the error message is relatively clear as GHC error messages go. (That's faint praise, admittedly.) Doing this instead should work, though I'm away from a Haskell compiler and can't run it:

```
func [1,2,3] [4,5] (\(a, b) -> a + b > 7)
```

Explanation: `\a b -> a + b > 7` is an anonymous function taking two arguments, `a` and `b`, whereas `\(a, b) -> a + b > 7` is an anonymous function taking a *single* argument which is a pair. The type of the last argument of `func`, `((a, b) -> Bool)`, is the type of the second anonymous function, not the first.

(This problem can also be fixed by making `func`'s last argument be of type `a -> b -> Bool`, while passing the first anonymous function.)

I originally thought OP's `tup` was just `zip`, and recommended they use `zip` instead to improve legibility. OP correctly points out that their function has very little in common with `zip` except the type.  There may still be a legibility win to be had, though; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119758/13018875).

Comment: But my function is not really Zip. Zip makes a list of tuples, each tuple containing elements of both lists occurring at the same position. 
But my function generates something like a Cartesian product from the 2 lists.

Comment: Oh, whoops! I'll edit.